# Image on top of another image - image will stay in the same place/coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to ask how to put an image/icon on top of the background-image or another image?

**The image/icon should stay in the same place/coordinate even if the size of the window changes, just like the idea of image mapping. The icon size should also be responsive to the screen/window size.**

I tried some answers from the previous questions, but it doesn't work. The image on top doesn't stay in the same place.

```
  <style>
    .page {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .bg {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .top {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: auto;
        top: 500px;
        left: 600px;
    }
</style>

<body>
<div class="page">
    <img class="bg" src="bg.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="top" src="plus.png" alt="">
</div>
</body>
```

**results here**

[fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMY5L.png)

[smaller screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8I9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a the background property directly on your div.page and then position your image inside it with a position: absolute. You can try the below for example, filling your images' url.

```css
.page {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.plus-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <img class="plus-icon" src="" alt="">
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work. 
What I'm looking for is if i put the icon on the edge of the rectangle, it will stay there even though i keep resizing my window. 

thank you tho

Comment: Can you please share all your code in a snippet ?